# Simple .htaccess Redirect causes infinity loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

Can anybody help me? I'm using this simple statement to redirect the root index.htm to the root directory /

```
Redirect 301 /index.htm /
```

But this causes an infinity loop. It redirects to my root, so it does the job. But now it's impossible to send requests to the root without getting an error telling you something about infinite redirects. My question: Why? And how to avoid this?

€dit: Now I have exactly this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^((.*)/)?index.[(php)(htm)(html)] $1
[R=301,L]
```

If i comment out one of these rules, the other runs perfectly. However, having both of these rules causes a rewrite to the root in every case. Please help!

€dit 2:

What I want is handling all incoming request with one single index.php file and redirecting every index.php, index.htm and index.html to it's directory because of duplicate content. How to do that?

€dit 3:

Now everything works like a charm!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#Redirects http://host.tld/gamedev to http://gamedev.host.tld/
Redirect 301 /gamedev/ http://gamedev.host.tld/

#Redirects every request to a subdirectory's index file to the subdirectory because of duplicated content
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)/index.(php|html?)$ http://gamedev.host.tld/$1

#Remove index file from a root folder request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ / [R=302,L]

#Handling all incoming requests with index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks a lot
Darth Moon

Comment: Most likely your http server is configured to deliver a `index.htm` file as directory index.

Comment: But without my rule index.htm won't be redirected to the root. Otherwise I wouldn't need the redirect

Comment: Can you explain what you want to archieve with the 2 rewrite rules (especially the first 1)? Maybe some examples would be helpful.

Comment: The first one should make every request handled by the index.php file

Comment: @DarthMoon: I think you should look at the answer from DocRoot. It should make exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule . index.php [NC,QSA,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^((.*)/)?index.[(php)(htm)(html)] $1
> [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> ...having both of these rules causes a rewrite to the root in every case.

Because after the first rule has rewritten the request to `index.php`, the rewritting process starts over and the second rule then strips *everything* from the URL.

Your second rule is incorrect. It's not matching what you thinks it's matching and is unnecessarily matching against any URL-path. You stated that this only needs to match the index document in the root.

`[(php)(htm)(html)]` - Presumably the intention is to match any of these file extensions, but instead this matches a single character: `p`, `h`, `t`, `m` or `l`. To match `php`, `htm` or `html` you need to use *alternation*. For example: `(php|htm|html)` or `(php|html?)`. (The `?` makes the `l` optional in the 2nd pattern.)

These directives are also in the wrong order. The external redirect should be *before* your front-controller.

@Benjamin's answer is pretty much on the button, except for the *condition* (that will never match) and that this must go at the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Remove /index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=302,L]

# Front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The `QSA` or `NC` flags were not required on your rewrite.

The reason for checking against `THE_REQUEST` in the first condition is to prevent a redirect loop (in some situations). `THE_REQUEST` contains the `Host` header from the initial request and does not change after URL rewriting.

Test with `302` (temporary) redirects and only change this to `301` (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic. As always, you must ensure your browser cache is clear before testing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can to this with a "Simple Redirection". The reason why you are getting the infinity loop is that the your apache is tring to deliver the content of the file `/index.htm` when you accessing the root directory `/` because it's part of the directory index list. Now your redirection takes effect (because you *virtual* accessing the page `/index.htm`) and the procedure starts from the beginning.

To solve your problem you should use a rewrite rule instead of a redirection. The rewrite rule only affects to the requested URL and doesn't end in an infinity loop. The following rule should work in your case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.htm
RewriteRule ^index.htm$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directive will never match in this example, so the redirect never occurs. `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the `Host` HTTP request header, eg. `GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1`. So you you would need a pattern like `\s/index\.htm` instead.

Comment: I saw it. It should be something like %{REQUEST_FILENAME}. But that doesn't solve my new problem. See my edit.

Comment: @DarthMoon No, this _redirect_ shouldn't be anything like `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`?!

Comment: @DocRoot: Thanks for the hint. If corrected the pattern. My browser has cached the redirection so it also worked when I tested the redirection from above. Sorry.